# Unable to install Office 2007 x64 on Windows 7 via GPO

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, microsoft-office-2007

I have a GPO that I use to push Office 2007 to our XP and Vista clients in our 2003 domain. I just installed a Windows 7 x64 Pro RTM machine and I'm trying to install Office 2007 in the same manner, but it just won't install. Other software packages do install. Any ideas as to why it's not installing or where to look for failure logs? gpresult /v shows this GPO as being applied to this computer.

```
 Software Installations
    ----------------------

        GPO: Office 2007 64-bit
            Name:             Microsoft Office Office 64-bit Components 2007
            Version:          12.0
            Deployment State: Assigned
            Source:           \\server\share\Software\Office\Microsoft Office 2007\Standard.WW\Office64WW.msi
            AutoInstall:      True
            Origin:           Applied Application
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: apparently, the 64-bit installer is just some office components, not the entire suite. You're still supposed to use the regular 32-bit installer even for 64-bit machines. Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Just a few clarification questions... The same GPO policy works for XP and Vista right? Are either of those 64bit systems? The main thing I could think of is a security problem, or maybe it not liking the spaces in your source. But if you had other packages install in similar circumstances...

Comment: I just confirmed that it is working with the 32bit GPO, I will have to spin up a 64bit Vista VM to verify that one. They both work out of the same directory, one just uses the 64bit specific msi. I also thought of the spaces in the directory, but that's one hell of a regression from Vista to 7...